# Discord Message Fetch: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'guild id'

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the first time I have tried to fetch a linked message within Discord, but I am getting stuck with the design of it.  Online I found code that allows you to grab that message link and be able to use it in a command, code is below:

```
if msg.lower().startswith('giveaway'): 
      link = 'https://discordapp.com/channels/guild_id/channel_id/message_id'.split('/')
      message = await client.get_guild(int(link[-3])).get_channel(int(link[-2])).fetch_message(int(link[-1]))
      server_id = int(link[4])
      channel_id = int(link[6])
      msg_id = int(link[5])
      server = client.get_guild(server_id)
      channel = server.get_channel(channel_id)
      message = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
      channell = client.get_channel(******************)
      await channell.send(f"{message.author.mention} Report Spam {link}")
```

As the *Title* suggests I am then getting an error message when I am trying to convert it, which is weird as I have no way to manipulate the guild.id value

```
message = await client.get_guild(int(link[-3])).get_channel(int(link[-2])).
```

The end outcome is for it to post the user reported, some text and the message link

Hopefully someone will point out the error in my ways!
(complete novice in Python)

Comment: How are you supposed to cast the string `"guild_id"` into an integer of base 10?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if msg.lower().startswith('giveaway'): 
      server_id = message.guild.id
      channel_id = message.channel.id
      msg_id = message.id #message.message.id
      link = 'https://discordapp.com/channels/' + str(server_id) + '/' + str(channel_id) + '/' + str(msg_id)

      channell = client.get_channel(880833232193597480)
      await channell.send(f"{message.author.mention} Report Spam {link}")
```

I managed to change it by using the above